# What is the typical range of the percentage of energy conversion in magnetic reconnection?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, plasma-physics

I want to determine a suitable range for the efficiency energy conversion of magnetic energy to thermal energy in usual magnetic reconnection because usually it is said that this process is highly efficient but I want to put some numbers there and of course try to compare with other processes to explain why it is an efficient process.

Comment: Due to law of energy conservation, all lost magnetic energy converts to some other form of energy. Efficiency refers to conversion to a useful form of energy, which is not defined here. It would be better to ask what percentage of magnetic energy turns into plasma internal energy, or what percentage turns into plasma kinetic energy, or other specified form of energy. Without specified the desired form, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question and in simple words I want to determine how "efficient" is the magnetic to thermal energy conversion due to magnetic reconnection processes.